# Trying to count the number of articles in a category but give wrong number

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, articles

I'm trying to use some PHP I found on here to count all the articles in a specific category (10), the PHP is working but only showing 20 articles, when a manual count shows 28.

```
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel');

$model->setState('filter.category_id', 10); // Set category ID here

$articles = $model->getItems();

$num_articles = count($articles);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `getItems` method, then `populateState` method is called, which overwrites `list.limit`.

`populateState` method has a comment.

> This method should only be called once per instantiation and is designed to be called on the first call to the getState() method unless the model configuration flag to ignore the request is set.

So, to deny calling `populateState` automatically, simply add `ignore_request` to `$config` array (third variable in `JModelLegacy::getInstance`).

```
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array( 'ignore_request' => true )); // add ignore_request

$params = JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();
$model->setState('params', $params); // Set params to avoid Fatal error

$model->setState('filter.category_id', 10); // Set category ID here
$model->setState('list.limit', 0); // Remove limit

$articles     = $model->getItems();

// getTotal result is already cached, just retrieve it
$num_articles = $model->getTotal();
```

**UPDATE**

If you only need count of articles, you could and should use `JModelList` method `getTotal`, which is faster way to get results count.

```
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array( 'ignore_request' => true )); // add ignore_request

$params = JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();
$model->setState('params', $params); // Set params to avoid Fatal error

$model->setState('filter.category_id', 10); // Set category ID here

// getTotal clears limit and offset, so setting list.limit to 0 is not needed
$num_articles = $model->getTotal();
```

Comment: Hi, when I add array( 'ignore_request' => true )); to the code I then get a Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object. Any idea?

Comment: Propably `params` is missing from state. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9809987/1960712) answer, try this solution and let me know. See my edited code.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
...
$model->setState('filter.category_id', 10); // Set category ID here
$model->setState('list.limit', 0);
...
```

in combination with `ignore_request` (see [Rene Korss answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/9741/154))

I found another solution how you can set the list.limit of the model without adding ignore_request to your model. Add these lines before you call getItems:

```
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $app->input->set('list', array('limit' => 0));
```

Otherwise the default limit gets applied to getItems (which is 20).

Comment: Hi,I added this to my code and it sill does not work. If I set the default in the global config to 100 it does return 28. But I really don't want to set that in global config. If I add echo $model->getState('list.limit'); to see what it is set to it still returns 20 and not any value I have set previously.

Comment: Which Joomla version are you using?

Comment: Joomla 3.4.1, it seems that the getItems() sets it's own list.limit when it gets called.

Comment: IMHO it should use the 'list.limit' from the state: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/f6c93e0294ba6e75b9604366f71bcf6b66970c04/libraries/legacy/model/list.php#L169

Comment: I have added an echo straight after the setState and it is still returning 20. $model->setState('list.limit',0);
echo $model->getState('list.limit');

Comment: ignore_request was missing in the getInstance call. See Rene Korss answer please.

Comment: Thank you for your help now fixed with yours and Rene's help.